# Using Instafeed and SimplyScroll Together

Tags: javascript, html, simplyscroll

Attempting to use SimplyScroll to scroll Instagram images, but can't determine the proper HTML markup to get the two scripts to function together.

I'm a super novice web designer, and I've done days of research in trying to work out the correct JavaScript HTML to get these two scripts working together, but to no avail. Any assistance, or direction to resources is appreciated!

Best as I can understand, the correct method is to create a target ID with the Instafeed HTML , which SimplyScroll calls as the source images.

Closest I've gotten so far is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
get: 'user',
target: 'instagram_list',
userId: XXXXXXXXXXX,
limit: 15,
accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
resolution: 'thumbnail',
after: function() {
$("#instagram_list").simplyScroll({
  speed: 1,
  frameRate: 20,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  direction: 'forwards',
  customClass: 'instagram_scroller'
});
}
});
(jQuery);
feed.run();
</script> 

<div id="instagram_list" class="simply-scroll-clip"> </div>
```

In this example, Instafeed loads the images, but is not styled properly and does not scroll. If the user reloads the page (not refresh, but instead selects the URL in the browser and hits enter) it works as intended.

I'm completely stumped on how and why it works on page reload only.

Link for the semi-working page is below

http://integrantsightsandsounds.com/instatest32.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to fiddle around a bit to get this working, I've put it on a site I did for a friend, you can have a look if it helps (http://www.zervasandpepper.com - warning, it plays music when you load it!) I still want to tweak it a bit e.g. prevent the row from overlapping when loading but it does work as intended.

I imported the required scripts, including SimplyScroll JavaScript, Instafeed JavaScript and the SimplyScroll css.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/Plugins/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/Plugins/instafeed.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/Plugins/jquery.simplyscroll.css" media="all"
        type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(function () { //on DOM ready 
                var feed = new Instafeed({
                    get: 'user',
                    userId: XXXXXXXX,
                    clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                });
                feed.run();
                $("#instafeed").simplyScroll({
                    autoMode: 'bounce',
                    startOnLoad: true,
                    auto: true,
                    speed: 1,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    pauseOnTouch: true
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

The ordering of the commands made me wonder if something is being ordered in your JavaScript to prevent the scrolling happening once the images are loaded. This may explain why the pictures scroll once they're already loaded up by Instagram.

Try the script as follows on your site (tweak as required) and see if it helps, it creates the feed and then applies the scroll:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(function () { //on DOM ready 
                  var feed = new Instafeed({
              get: 'user',
              target: 'instagram_list',
              userId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXx,
              limit: 15,
              accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
              resolution: 'thumbnail'
                                });
                                feed.run();
                                $("#instagram_list").simplyScroll({
                  speed: 1,
                  frameRate: 20,
                  orientation: 'horizontal',
                  direction: 'forwards',
                  customClass: 'instagram_scroller'
                }); 
                            });
                        })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it :) You can mark as the useful answer if it is working now. Looking forward to seeing it on your site! Emma

Comment: Updating due to Instagram's new requirements and stumped again.

The following setup generates the error, ReferenceError 'Can't find variable: Instafeed' in Safari's Error Console. Going out of my mind trying to figure it out!

Comment: ...sorry, didn't mean to tag your answer with a new problem! Trying to add to the thread.